# PHP Appending same value to two variables

Tags: php

I need to append a value to two variables.

```
$a = "String A";
$b = "String B";
```

...

```
$a .= " more";
$b .= " more";
```

Is there a shorter way to get this work?

`$a .= $b .= " more";` is not doing what I want.

Thanks in Advance,
Matty

Comment: The way you are doing is okay. And both the variable holds different values.

Comment: For two or three vars that's ok. If you have more, consider making a function.

Comment: You can't do that, with this, $a="String AString B more" and $b="String B more" is there is few of var to assign, make it like your first idea, else, just create a function to assign value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.

```
$a .= $b .= " more";
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$b .= " more";
$a .= $b;
```

The best way is to write:

```
$a .= " more";
$b .= " more";
```

---

Or (if you have a lot of them) use array with some functions:

#1 - array_map approach

```
function addMore(&$vars) {
    $var .= " more";
}
$array = [$a, $b];
$array = array_map('addMore',$array);
```

#2 - classic approach:

```
$array = array($a, $b);
foreach ($array_before as &$var) {
    $var .= " more";
}
```